# QGIS data defined labelling using attribute fields in shapefile

Tags: qgis, labeling, data-defined-override

I usually override automatic labelling by storing the X and Y coordinates of labels in manually created fields in my shapefile. I find that when using auxiliary storage in the project file, QGIS tends to become slower when working on big projects.

I never had problems with this method until now. I created my two fields again and also one for the angle of rotation but when I want to manually move my labels, the moment I click it, it wants me to choose a primary key for an auxiliary storage again. When I click on cancel, it tells me in 4 error messages on top that the labelling anchor text field does not exist in this layer and neither do the labelling anchor type field, the labelling anchor cut field and the labelling anchor percent field...

I think we know it has got to do something with the anchor settings but when I checked, all was set to standard. I didn't change any anchor settings.

Did anyone have a similar problem or know what I can look for?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.
My overall setting for the labelling of the line objects was parallel labelling which requires anchor settings in order to determine where on the lines the labels should be anchored. It turns out that when you want to store the labels locations into your shapefile, you also need to create fields to store the anchor settings in.
When you change the overall placement settings to horizontal, X and Y fields are enough to store the labels locations but the rotations of the parallel labels are lost.
One workaround might be to extract the rotation values of the lines which you can link then to the rotation value of the labels.